# Java : use of Curly braces inside Pattern.compile

Tags: java

I am working on a existing code , where i have this piece of code which is responsible to remove symbols if it belongs to yesterday .

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            String currentSymbol = "TEST JUL 20 2013";
            Pattern datePattern = Pattern
                    .compile("(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC) \\d{2} \\d{4}");
            Matcher dateMatcher = datePattern.matcher(currentSymbol);
            if (dateMatcher.find()) {
                System.out.println("Inside dateMatcher.find");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not Inside dateMatcher.find");
            }
        } catch (Exception t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

This code works fine , but could anybody please tell me what is the need of this  `\\d{2} \\d{4}` at this line , what does this mean

```
        Pattern datePattern = Pattern
                .compile("(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC) \\d{2} \\d{4}");
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It matches some month followed by a 2-digit number then a 4-digit number: `Jan 14 2012`

Answer (score 12):

Look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

- `\\d` is the character class "Decimal" - so any digit from 0 to 9.
- `{2}` specifies "previous expression must appear exactly 2 times"

so:

- `\\d{2}` matches any 2-digit number
- `\\d{4}` matches any 4-digit number

Answer (score 1):

The `\\d` refers to a decimal digit (0-9 in layman's terms) and the number in the curly braces is the exact number of occurrences to expect.

In your case, the {2} matches the two digits of the month and the {4} matches four digits of the year.